# Is there a name for $(x, f(x))$?

Tags: functions, terminology

Given a function $f$, and an $x$ from its domain, is there a name for the pair $(x, f(x))$?

Is there a defined terminology for one (any) such pair? I think the set of all $(x, f(x))$ is called the graph of the function, but I am asking is there's a name for one (or any) point of the graph.

Comment: I think calling it a point on the graph is fine.

Comment: Technically it’s an element of the function but people would probably be confused if you said that.

Comment: @PrinceM I would like to disagree with this statement.  While one way to formally define a function from $X$ to $Y$ is as a subset of $X\times Y$ satisfying certain properties, this is essentially only used in set theory/foundations of mathematics.  Everywhere else, a function is simply a way to associate an element of $Y$ to each element of $X$, and that set would be the graph. It's the same way that an ordered pair isn't actually a set of the form $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$, that is merely a convenient definition for foundations.  This is *why* people would be confused if you said that.

Comment: The first word of my comment is “technically” and “technically” a function is rigorously defined in set theory / analysis. As mathematics develops the notation and terminology develops to more intuitive conventions. It doesn’t mean the “definition changes”, the level of rigor we use when talking about the concept is what changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this *an element of the graph of $f$*, or an element of $\Delta(f)$ where $\Delta$ sends symbols to their denotations, or *an element of $f$ as a set*.

This amounts to the same thing as calling it *an element of $f$*, as suggested in the comments, except that it makes explicit the act of sending a function to its corresponding set. This operation is a no-op if you think of a function as just a set of pairs. It is not a no-op if you think of it as an ordered triple with its domain, codomain, and graph as elements, or if you think of a function as some kind of non-set entity.

Comment: What does it mean when an answer is part of community wiki?

Comment: @SomeGuy From a reputation perspective, it means that the author does not receive or lose reputation based on what happens to the question. I think most people use it to report ideas that aren't theirs and surface them as answers or to answer certain kinds of questions that "one shouldn't receive rep for". I used it in this case because the answer is not entirely original; it strongly references what DMcMor and Prince M said in the comments.

Comment: If youre worried about credit, why not credit them in your answer? Also how do I make a community wiki answer?

Comment: I think this discussion is more appropriate on meta than here. When surfacing a good comment as an answer to a question or doing that and adding some of my own take, I usually credit the comments generically and make the answer community wiki. You can make your own answer community wiki by clicking the box in the answer window. You can also make it CW after the fact.

Comment: Sorry I probably did not give enough context for my question. The context is actually giving a name for this construct in a software component. I knew that (x,f(x)) can be referred to as an element of a graph of a function, but that's way too convoluted to be an actual concise term. But, as I take from all the answers that there isn't any description that is more concise than this, I can mark this as accepted.

Comment: If you are okay with a new term you can call it an `entry` or a `row` (in addition to `point` which has already been suggested). Also, if it's part of a software package, it might make sense just to call it a `pair`. Every pair is an element of the graph of some function. Having an intuitive representation for functions is also a key motivation for defining pairs, perhaps *the* key motivation.

Answer (score 0):

I call this the graph of a function and I use $\Gamma = (x,f(x))$ as the notation.

Answer (score -1):

It's called an ordered pair and it is usually written as $(x,y)$ instead of $(x,f(x))$ because $y=f(x)$. It's called an ordered pair because it's a pair of numbers, and the order matter. For example, $(2,3)$ is different from $(3,2)$.

You may read more about it here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair

Or watch some videos on this topic here

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-sixth-grade-math/cc-6th-negative-number-topic/cc-6th-coordinate-plane/v/plot-ordered-pairs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlT726odQcM

Comment: The term 'ordered pair' refers to *any* pair $(a,b)$ where the order of $a$ and $b$ matters.  This is more general than the situation described in the question.

Comment: @DMcMor, right, but it still applies here